# I have remote-ssh to the wsl2 in vscode. And I can launch vscode in the terminal of vscode. But I can't launch vscode in the windows terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKPmq.png)
When I echo $PATH in the terminal of vscode,and in the windows termianl,the output results also different.
who can solve this problem?thanks!

the results of "echo $PATH " are different.